# Swift : Query Dictionary using value

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, xcode8

I have a dictionary but I need to query by particular value to get the key. But it seems like swift doesn't have valueforKey function.

Example:

```
print(myDictionary["key"])
//output: 100

//but I want to get:
print(myDictionary.valueForkey:"100")
//output: key
```

Any of you knows how can I do this in swift?

Comment: Your code implies `keyForValue`... ;-)

Comment: @vadian, you are righ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do that in Swift because dictionaries can be represented by tuples:

```
let myDictionary = ["foo": 100, "baz" : 200]

if let found = myDictionary.filter({ $0.1 == 100 }).first {
    let key = found.0
    print(key) // "foo"
}
```

Comment: this works. I like swift but I think Objective-C is more cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: There are some more sophisticated (and generic) solutions in the duplicate question.